# php MySql Get Newer Posts Than Current Available Post By Using Its Random ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `News Feed System` that gets newer posts than currents available last post by getting currents available last posts id and search for it in db like that

```
    SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id > $current_last_post
```

that works.. but it's not secure for comments if someone wants to `spam` he can `spam` all the posts in the db because I am posting comments by getting the posts id and insert into a table called comments i can fix that by giving the posts a `unique id` like something like that `E9dQ3Fv` but that won't work out for getting new posts because how can you compare like that

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id > E9dQ3Fv` .

can you suggest me something that works with the Unique IDs ?

**EDIT: So my question**

> is it possible to get newer posts using random IDs instead old normal Autoincremented IDs or i have to add both the normal one and the random get latest posts by the normal IDs and post comments using the random IDs?

i hope you understand me...
thanks (sorry for bad English)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Ok i edited it a little but i hope you get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1

Use an additional column in addition to your `random id` that maintains the sort order. E.g. a `TIMESTAMP` column or just an auto incrementing id.

## Option 2

Replace your random id with a pseudo-random value that monotonically increases. e.g. an int sequence that instead of increasing by 1 each time increases by a random amount (1, 4, 23, 678, 680, 1221, ...)

I couldn't work out *why* you needed a random ID so it's not possible for me to know if this would be suitable or not.

Comment: Thanks the second one looks like its working for me , But does it make my page load slower ? i mean is it possible to limit the random number to 2 or 3 number instead of 4 /

Comment: EDIT: first one worked what i did was i created another column and named it rand_id which will i use to post comments without getting my db spammed and i get newer posts by using the regular id which is auto incremented, thats a more secure way i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()` if you want to randomize your results but this is not encouraged (it's slow on large tables).

Comment: I don't *think* this is what he wants, as I understand it he wants the results ordered by date / insertion time, not randomly.

Comment: No thats not what i am looking for